# Network going down at server side after 1 minute once RTSP requested from Client

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, ip-camera, rtsp-client

I am using VGA camera at input side and framegrabber for H.264 compression. I am getting RTSP stream from framegrabber over ethernet. this stream has been connected to Server laptop with point to point connection.

When I request a RTSP stream from Client side using gstreamer (sometimes VLC), I get the stream for max 1 minute. After 1 minute the network from server side is going down. only server WiFi connection getting disturbed. Client is alive in this case too.
I am unable to troubleshoot the exact problem.

I did some wireshark testing with different inputs:
1. Framegrabber with VGA camera
2. Surveillence camera

It work perfectly fine with serveillence camera.

One thing which I have seen is even there is network breakdown, framegrabber is keep sending frames to server. Normally it has to stop but it is keep sending it. I am confuse here also.

Configuration:
Framegrabber: 
bitrate - 1 Mbps
Resolution - 720 * 480
Framerate - 30fps ( can not be changed because of use of PAL )

Same with surveillence camera except framerate is 25fps.

Please guide me for solving network breakdown issue.

Thanks in advance!!!